# How to check a cell for an element in tic-tac-toe game?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JS and have created my first tic-tac-toe game. When I put any character, I assign a private class to them, but I ran into a problem, how do I check that a cell that already has an element is occupied, that is, how can I forbid assigning a second class and forbid replacing an element

```
for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML+='<div class="block"></div>';
}

let game = document.getElementById('game');
let blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
let res = document.querySelector('.result');
let btnGame = document.querySelector('.new-game');
let currentPlayer = document.getElementById('cur-plr');

let step = false;
let player = '';
let score = {
    'x': 0,
    'o': 0,
    'd': 0,
};
let count = 0;
let playerOne = 'x';
let playerSecond = '0';

const isPlayerOneWin = (blocks, comb, i) => blocks[comb[i][0]].classList.contains('playerOne') && blocks[comb[i][1]].classList.contains('playerOne') && blocks[comb[i][2]].classList.contains('playerOne');

const isPlayerSecondWin = (blocks, comb, i) => blocks[comb[i][0]].classList.contains('playerSecond') && blocks[comb[i][1]].classList.contains('playerSecond') && blocks[comb[i][2]].classList.contains('playerSecond');

function AddClassActive (blocks, comb, i) {
    blocks[comb[i][0]].classList.add('active');
    blocks[comb[i][1]].classList.add('active');
    blocks[comb[i][2]].classList.add('active');
};

function AddClassNegative (blocks, comb, i) {
    blocks[comb[i][0]].classList.add('negative');
    blocks[comb[i][1]].classList.add('negative');
    blocks[comb[i][2]].classList.add('negative');
};

function stepPlayerOne(target) {
    target.innerHTML = playerOne
    target.classList.add('playerOne');
    count++;
};

function stepPlayerSecond(target) {
    target.innerHTML = playerSecond
    target.classList.add('playerSecond');
    count++;
};

function init(e) {
     if(!step) stepPlayerOne(e.target); 
     else stepPlayerSecond(e.target);
     step = !step;
     player = player == '0' ? 'x' : '0';
     currentPlayer.innerHTML = player.toUpperCase();
     checkWin();

};

function newGame() {
    step = false;
    count= 0;
    res.innerText = '';
    blocks.forEach(item => {
        item.innerHTML = '';
        currentPlayer.innerHTML = '';
        item.classList.remove('playerOne', 'playerSecond', 'active', 'negative');
        game.addEventListener('click', init);
        updateScore()
    })
};

function updateScore() {
    document.getElementById('sX').innerHTML = score.x;
    document.getElementById('sO').innerHTML = score.o;
    document.getElementById('sD').innerHTML = score.d;
}

function checkWin() {
    let comb = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < comb.length; i++) {

        if (isPlayerOneWin(blocks, comb, i)) {
            AddClassActive(blocks, comb, i);
            res.innerText = 'Cross Win';
            game.removeEventListener('click', init)
            score.x += 1
        }

        else if (isPlayerSecondWin(blocks, comb, i)) {
            AddClassActive(blocks, comb, i)
            res.innerText = 'Zero Win';
            game.removeEventListener('click', init)
            score.o += 1
        }

        else if (count == 9 && i === 7) {
            AddClassNegative(blocks, comb, i)
            res.innerText = 'Draw, try again';
            game.removeEventListener('click', init);
            console.log(score.d);
            score.d += 1;
        }
    }
};

btnGame.addEventListener('click', newGame);
game.addEventListener('click', init);
```

I tried to do a check, but I guess I'm not doing it right here, tell me how can I do it right?
that's an example

```
function stepPlayerSecond(target) {
    if(target.innerHTML = playerSecond) {
        target.classList.add('playerSecond');
    }
    else {
        remove();
    }
    count++;
};
```

Comment: `if(target.innerHTML = playerSecond)` - that would be an _assignment_, not a comparison.

Comment: https://codepen.io/spark25/pen/eYeBXmG

Comment: what could be the condition?